# CN1 MultiImage sizes compared to Android dpi resource folders

Tags: codenameone

Is there a simple mapping between Codename One `MultiImage` sizes and Android's drawable resource folders?

When importing any image into CN1 as a multi-image, the following size options are given, no matter what size the base image file is:

- Very Low: 28x28
- Low:      36x36
- Medium:   48x48
- High:     72x72
- Very High: 96x96
- HD:       196x196

According the [Android iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html), the following relative sizes should be used when creating drawables for the different folders:

- MDPI: 1x
- HDPI: 1.5x
- XHDPI: 2x
- XXHDPI: 3x
- XXXHDPI: 4x

---

This suggests the following mapping of Android dpi resources to CN1 multi-image sizes:

- LDPI --> Low
- MDPI --> Medium
- HDPI --> High
- XHDPI --> Very High
- XXHDPI --> HD

Coming from an Android background, this seems to simplify the concept quite nicely; is this correct?

---

To preempt, I have watched the MultiImage video in the [How Do I? section](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i.html), as well as the Android Trail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you look at the AndroidImplementation source file in SVN you will see this block of code which will provide the definitive answer:

```
@Override
public int getDeviceDensity() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    switch (metrics.densityDpi) {
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
            return Display.DENSITY_LOW;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        case 213: // DENSITY_TV 
            return Display.DENSITY_HIGH;
        case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
            return Display.DENSITY_VERY_HIGH;
        case 480: // DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH
            return Display.DENSITY_HD;
        default:
            return Display.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
    }
}
```

Comment: We used to do something similar in our BlackBerry library, so the concept is not new to me. Nice though, that the sizing bins match with Android so well, as Android is my current focus.